# How to trigger the On Click function of a button in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my script I want to trigger a Click function of a button I thought I can do something like:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Button>().Click();
```

but this dont work.

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Button>().onClick;
```

Maybe I can do it with this but I dont even know what it does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.Invoke();
```

[`UnityEvent.Invoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.Invoke.html)

> I dont even know what `onClick` does

Go to the documentation:

[`Button.onClick`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html)

Answer (score 1):

In Unity, the `onClick` event of a Button component is activated when the button is initially pressed. However, we can enhance its functionality using `UnityEvent.AddListener`. By doing so, the added `UnityAction` will be executed when the Button press is released instead.

For executing a button click using C# script use the following code,

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.Invoke();
```

For invoking additional functionality on the button press refer the following code,

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Make sure to attach these Buttons in the Inspector
    public Button m_YourFirstButton, m_YourSecondButton, m_YourThirdButton;

    void Start()
    {
        //Calls the TaskOnClick/TaskWithParameters/ButtonClicked method when you click the Button
        m_YourFirstButton.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        m_YourSecondButton.onClick.AddListener(delegate {TaskWithParameters("Hello"); });
        m_YourThirdButton.onClick.AddListener(() => ButtonClicked(42));
        m_YourThirdButton.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    }

    void TaskOnClick()
    {
        //Output this to console when Button1 or Button3 is clicked
        Debug.Log("You have clicked the button!");
    }

    void TaskWithParameters(string message)
    {
        //Output this to console when the Button2 is clicked
        Debug.Log(message);
    }

    void ButtonClicked(int buttonNo)
    {
        //Output this to console when the Button3 is clicked
        Debug.Log("Button clicked = " + buttonNo);
    }
}
```

For more: https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html